# Search special pattern in string: R

Tags: r, regex

I like to know the number of `0`'s which are surrounded by `1`. But if there are more than one `0` without interrupted by a `1` it count only as one.

```
string <- "1101000010101111001110"
```

This is the closest I'm able to do:

```
length(gregexpr(pattern ="101",string)[[1]])
```

**Expected output:**

```
5
```

Comment: Shouldn't pattern be `10+1` as you are looking for **more than one 0** ? Try it and let me know.

Comment: @Rahul thanks when there is more than one 0 it work now. But how i do when the pattern is overlapping?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

With `gregexpr` you can use lookahead assertion with `perl=True` to find overlapping matches:

`(?=...)` is a [**lookahead assertion**](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#Lookaround-Assertions):

> `(?=...)`
>
> A zero-width positive lookahead assertion. For example, `/\w+(?=\t)/` matches a word followed by a tab, without including the tab in `$&`.

```
length(gregexpr("(?=10+1)", string, perl=TRUE)[[1]])
```